# Comparing entire url through Assert.assertEquals

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng, assert

I want to compare the url and print, so I have used the below code. But it was comparing the whole url like as below

Actual comparison done for the below url :

```
https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=
```

Code I have used :

```
String URL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
Assert.assertEquals(URL, "https://accounts.google.com" );
System.out.println(URL);
```

Solution needed:

I want compare only the 'https://accounts.google.com'

Please help me out to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used below code and it working fine for me

```
String URL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    if(URL.contains("url name"))
    {
        System.out.println("Landed in correct URL" +
                "" + URL);

    }else
    {
        System.out.println("Landed in wrong URL");

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you access the *url* `https://accounts.google.com` the *url* is set as :

```
https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=
```

This *url* is **dynamic** in nature. So you won't be able to use `assertEquals()` as :

- `assertEquals()` is defined as :

  ```
  void org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(String actual, String expected)

  Asserts that two Strings are equal. If they are not, an AssertionError is thrown.

  Parameters:
      actual the actual value
      expected the expected value
  ```

So `assertEquals()` will validate if two *Strings* are identical. Hence you see the error.

### Solution

To assert the presence of `https://accounts.google.com` within the *current url* you can use the function `Assert.assertTrue()` as follows :

```
String URL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
Assert.assertTrue(URL.contains("https://accounts.google.com"));
System.out.println(URL);
```

### Explanation

- `assertTrue()` is defined as :

  ```
  void org.testng.Assert.assertTrue(boolean condition)

  Asserts that a condition is true. If it isn't, an AssertionError is thrown.

  Parameters:
      condition the condition to evaluate
  ```

Comment: No, it's not worked for me. even i have tried the both " equals,contains & true)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should not use 'assertEquals' instead use 'assertTrue'

```
Assert.assertTrue(URL.startsWith("https://accounts.google.com"));
```

Comment: I have tried with above code but shows error as "java.lang.AssertionError: expected [true] but found [false]"

Comment: String URL = "https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache="; String expectedURL = "https://accounts.google.com"; Assert.assertTrue(URL.startsWith(expectedURL)); if the above URLs are correct, it should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to remove the Assert.assertTrue and check your url then use this simple technique as below code. AssertEquals, Assertions
`Assert.assertTrue(url.equals("https://www.instagram.com/hiteshsingh00/?hl=en"));`

can also be written as
`Assert.assertEquals(true,url.equals("https://www.instagram.com/hiteshsingh00/?hl=en"));`

also `assertTrue(x == 2);`
`assertEquals(2,x);`